# How to fill background of website even when a mobile browser alters it's height on scroll?

Tags: android, html, css, image, background-image

I have a website that i'm trying to design. I've filled the background with an image that takes 100% of the height of the screen. On a computer this works perfectly, but on mobile it only takes 100% of the webpage space available at load, which includes the browswer's URL bar at the top. When you scroll down, the URL bar disappears that leaves a gap at the bottom of the background of website.

The website is a single webpage website. The 'homepage'/initial view on load fades in to the background image. I want the actual content to be just off the screen on load, and so having a background image that just fills 100% of the height of the screen is important.

How do i fix this?

Below is how i've filled the background and screenshots of the website in question.

I've filled the background of the website using the following CSS code.

```
html{
    background: url(../content/BackgroundAndHand03.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[Website with mobile browser URL bar](https://s28.postimg.org/4nb5nj1kt/2017_02_24_02_21_10.png)

[Website without mobile browser URL bar](https://s28.postimg.org/j58cvisvx/2017_02_24_02_21_05.png)

Answer (score 1):

This prevents scrolling past the `html` element and allows your `body` to maintain its position during over-scroll on mobile devices, so even if the device supports over-scroll, the `html` is locked to the desired color or image while the `body` moves.

```
html {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Make sure to include this `meta` tag if you already haven't

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I found that this doesn't work for me. It doesn't fix the gap in the bottom of the background image. The overflow control locks the content of my webpage, even though html is the one set to hidden and body is set to auto.